# VBA connection to Java

Tags: java, javascript, excel, vba

I have an Excel with some macros. The data is currently sourced manually. In order to automate the report, I need to source the data directly from Oracle database. Unfortunately, this cannot be done, as it is a production database and passwords cannot be shared with anyone.

The next best possible approach is to connect via the Java layer. How can I connect VBA with a Java service?

Any conceptual starting points will also be appreciated.

Comment: yes, using Automation

Comment: please clarify, do you want to get data from Oracle **into Excel** or *the other way around, from Excel into Oracle* ?

Comment: Hi Philip....ORACLE-->JAVA-->Excel

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice API from Apache called POI for processing Microsoft documents. http://poi.apache.org/
The other approach is to use OLEDB driver for Excel which will allow you to read data from Excel exactly as you will do from any database using JDBC.

Comment: Hi Raza, i know about POI but thats using java to write excel. I want to connect to a JAVA API using VBA.

Comment: Sorry I thought you only want to read data from Excel files and dump it in your Oracle database. I agree with @Nick in your case. The best way to communicate will be XML. There is no direct link between VBA and Java, if you already have Java APIs that can receive XML then fine otherwise you may have to write some wrappers around your Java APIs to accept XML data from VBA. Also if you are using Servlets, it is a breeze, if Servlets are not an option then you can go the Sockets route and create your own connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Interop between different technologies likes this is commonly achieved with a combination http and xml.

It's a long time since I saw this done so the technologies might be out of date but you can create a [ADO record set from XML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263247).

Excel can make a http call to a Java server that returns the xml.  This xml can then be used to create a record set for Excel to consume just as if that record set were obtained directly from the database.